# Angularjs, select2 with dynamic tags and onclick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2, ui-select2

I use angularjs with "ui_select2" directive. Select2 draws new tags with formatting function, there are "" elements with "ng-click" attribute. How to tell angularjs about new DOM elements? Otherwise new "ng-clicks" wont work.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="contact_ids" ui-select2="unit.participantsOptions" ng-model="unit.contactIds" />
```

JS (angular controller):

```
anyFunction = function(id) {
    console.log(id)
}

formatContactSelection = function(state) {
    return "<a class=\"select2-search-choice-favorite\" tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"\" ng-click=\"anyFunction(state.id)\"></a>"
}

return $scope.unit.participantsOptions = {
    tags: [],
    formatSelection: formatContactSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
        return m
    },
    ajax: {
        url: '/contacts/search',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                term: term,
                limit: 20,
                page: page
            }
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            return {
                results: data,
                more: (page * 10) < data.total
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that select2 creates DOM elements, that not yet discovered by angularjs, I read that new DOM elements need to be appended to some element with using angularjs $compile  function, but I cannot use it in controller.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution - I created the directive, that watches for changes in ngModel and apply it on the element, that has already ui_select2 directive. "uiRequiredTags" implements custom behavior I need for my select2 tag choices. The solution is to watch changes in ngModel attribute.

```
angular.module("myAppModule", []).directive("uiRequiredTags", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            var opts;
            opts = scope.$eval("{" + attrs.uiRequiredTags + "}");
            return scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
                var $requireLink;
                $requireLink = el.parent().find(opts.path);
                $requireLink.off('click');
                $requireLink.on('click', function() {
                    var id, n, tagIds;
                    id = "" + ($(this).data('requiredTagId'));
                    if (opts.removeLinkPath && opts.innerContainer) {
                    $(this).parents(opts.innerContainer).find(opts.removeLinkPath).data('requiredTagId', id);
                }
                tagIds = scope.$eval(opts.model).split(',');
                n = tagIds.indexOf(id);
                if (n < 0) {
                    tagIds.push(id);
                } else {
                    tagIds.splice(n, 1);
                }
                scope.$eval("" + opts.model + " = '" + tagIds + "'");
                scope.$apply();
                return $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });

        });
    }
};
```